# CallDirectoryHandler IOS10 nsuserdefaults

Tags: ios10, callkit

I've been trying to use the new CallDirectoryHandler extension for IOS10
I'm using the official release.

First of all this extension is not debuggable and logs doesn't seems to work.

I'm trying to pass Parameters between my app to this extension via NSUserDefaults, it's not working the object that I get is empty.

Anyone has any idea how to pass parameters otherwise for this extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Application groups solved my problem.

NSUserDefaults *mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName: @"group.name.company.shared"];

Comment: please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837561/how-to-use-call-directory-extension-to-identify-a-incoming-call/40838374#40838374